# Is it possible for Etsy's StaggeredGridview to work in API 9?

Tags: android, staggered-gridview

I am using [Etsy's StaggeredGridview](https://github.com/etsy/AndroidStaggeredGrid) in my project. This library is supported from API 10+. But my project's minimum SDK version is 9.

However in their Github page, it is written that 'It could be modified to support older versions if required.'. But I dont know how to make it support for older versions.

Anyone have an idea on how to do this?

**Update:** Etsy's StaggeredGridView is deprecated. Please consider using RecyclerView with StaggeredGridLatoutManager.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change value of `minSdkVersion` into manifest of library project to 9

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="10"/>
```

with

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="9"/>
```

Comment: @SudheeshMohan Did you tried that? If yes what error you get then?

Comment: I am using this library by adding this in dependancies.  compile 'com.etsy.android.grid:library:1.0.5' . Where to find its manifest file?

Comment: You can clone the git project and add as local library project into your application. As this will be local library project, you can see there is a manifest as you can see at https://github.com/etsy/AndroidStaggeredGrid/blob/master/library/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml. I don't know if we can modify minsdk value from dependancy tag. Looking for that, if  will find, will update you.